# Cartodb Layer source object not loading

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js

I have tried to figure out why the layer is not showing up on the map. My code is as follows.

```
var markersLayerSource = {
    user_name: 'someaccount',
    type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: [{
            sql: baseSql,
            https: 'force https',
            cartocss: cartoCss,
            interactivity: 'cartodb_id'
            }]
        }

        cartodb.createLayer(map, markersLayerSource, {https: true})
            .addTo(map)
            .on('done', function (layer) {
            console.log(layer);
            layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteraction(true);
            layer.getSubLayer(0).on('featureOver', function(e, pos, pixel, data) {
                // print data to console log
                console.log("Event #" + data.cartodb_id + ", name " + data.name + ", max population: " + data.pop_max);
            });
            //layer.getSubLayer(0).show();
            //cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(0), ['cartodb_id']);
        });
```

Any one with pointers on why i specifically need to have cdb.viv.Vis.addInfowindow inorder for the layer to show up on the map? Am I doing something wrong if one needs to render without the addinfowindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check all the variables you have introduced within your `markerLayerSource` (the console will tell you what is wrong anyway). I have replicated your code [in this working example](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/ebf41884cff6c8cf60da623ee3296836). But I have used a different methodology to add the tooltip:

```
var tooltip = layer.leafletMap.viz.addOverlay({
    type: 'tooltip',
    layer: layer,
    template: '<div class="cartodb-tooltip-content-wrapper"> <div class="cartodb-tooltip-content"><h3>{{name}}</h3><p>{{pop_max}} inhabitants</p></div></div>', 
    width: 200,
    position: 'bottom|right',
    fields: [{ name: 'name' }, { pop_max: 'pop_max' }]
            });

$('body').append(tooltip.render().el);
```

So first, check that all your variables are well declared (`baseSql` and `cartoCss`) and secondly, try to use this methodology to add the tooltip. This is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this really helps. I did use the same base and using the queries as follows but there are some javascript issues with the points to some of the some layers. Any idea on what I am doing wrong? http://bl.ocks.org/jmwenda/raw/b472b0a932fc5b895a5e59dadac18192/

Comment: There is nothing showing in the console and also I am not sure what I am looking for. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, when hovering the different layers, the infowindows pop up in a haphazard manner. I.e hover the cursor on some of the points and infowindows are triggered at the wrong place on not shown at all.

Comment: `bind` is a Leaflet method, if you have a look at my block I have used a different (CARTO) methodology.

Comment: Thanks a million totally missed that! Changed to using .on but still having infowindows not appearing for some, the green point fails to trigger at all at time while the red point triggers several infowindows. Also depends on which is triggered first.