# Strange cartodb infowindow behavior

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js, infowindow

I have been working with some cartodb infowindows and some dynamic templating in showing the infowindows when hovering. Sadly when hovering on different sublayers, interactivity of the different sublayers seems to trigger non related events on other sublayers or not trigger the infowindow at all. Any pointers on what is wrong here?

http://bl.ocks.org/jmwenda/17c06e7257963b3d0cee9a4ce84882ac

Answer (score 1):

You are using again Leaflet.js methods to add iw and tooltips into CARTO sublayers. As I suggested you [in your last question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205765/cartodb-layer-source-object-not-loading), I will use CARTO.js methodology. In doing so, you will not have these kind of conflicts.

Comment: As far as I can tell there are no leaflet methods. the bind method in this case was replaced with the .on method which is a Carto method. Unless you are referreing to L.map and L.tilelayer which your example also have.

Comment: Those are Javascript event listeners. What I mean is that the block of codes  that are commented are the right methods to add tooltips, for example. Anyway you have created so many events, that is difficult to follow the chain/cascade.